# VectorDrawable bad rendering in android 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-vectordrawable

I have many vector icons and i tested them on different android versions but rendering of some of these vectors on android marshmallow is not correct, while on other android versions no problem and rendering is good.

gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

and on top of my activity

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

i'm using the latest appcompat version

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

Comment: That's not the latest AppCompat version. It is 25.0.0 at the moment.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is, "why am I getting poor rendering of the vectors?", you need to provide us with a [mcve]. The snippets you have here are fine, but we have no idea how you are using vectors, what vectors are giving you trouble, what you are seeing, and where are you are seeing the problems (beyond "marshmallow" -- what devices? what emulator configurations?).

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you, i thought 25 version is preview, i changed my appcompat to 25.0 and the problem is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to version 25.0.0 of the Support Library